# how to get an answer in the form of raw audio folder in android studio

Tags: android, audio

This array of questions and answers,
R.raw.ikhlas example is the question to answer R.raw.jwbalikhlas

```
int[] rawQuetion = {R.raw.alfalaq, R.raw.alikhlas, R.raw.alkafirun, R.raw.allahab};
int [] rawAnswer={R.raw.jwbaliklas};
```

This method to randomize questions

```
 //fisher-yates Shuffle
public void playSoal() {
    shuffleArray(rawQuetion);
    try{
        int idx = new Random().nextInt(rawQuetion.length);
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, rawQuetion[idx]);
        mp.start();

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("ERROR", "Media Player", e);
        mp = null;
        mp.release();
        mp.stop();
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}

static void shuffleArray(int[] arr)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
        // Swap
        int a = arr[index];
        arr[index] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = a;
    }
}
```

I want when the quiz questions selected at random, will answer here

```
public void audioFile() throws IOException{
    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.jwbaliklas);//I want this to be obtained from the above array

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    BufferedInputStream in = null;
    in = new BufferedInputStream(is);

    int read;
    byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
    while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0)
    {
        out.write(buff, 0, read);
    }
    out.flush();
    byte[] audioBytes = out.toByteArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < audioBytes.length; i++) {
        audioBytes[i] = (byte) ((audioBytes[i]) & 0xFF);       }

    absNormalizedSignal = hitungFFT(audioBytes);
    AppLog.logString("===== From audio File");


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass the array id for the resource you want to open, you can use the index directly from the array of integers (as long as it is visible from the `audioFile` scope.

```
public void audioFile(@RawRes int i) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(rawQuestion[i]);
    ...
}
```

Also, you have to change include the annotation `@RawRes`:

```
@RawRes int[] rawQuestion = {R.raw.alfalaq, R.raw.alikhlas, R.raw.alkafirun, R.raw.allahab};
@RawRes int[] rawAnswer = {R.raw.jwbaliklas};
```

Comment: I see . but I am still confused, how can I write code for R.raw.jwbaliklas is R.raw.alikhlas answer. so that there is at is InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(rawQuetion[i]); R.raw.jwbaliklas

Comment: You should annotate the variable with `@RawRes` (as I edited above)